# Error while testing soap service using HTTP Request in Jmeter

Tags: soap, jmeter, httprequest

I am trying to test a soap service using Jmeter. The service is giving proper results when SOAP/XML-RPC Request element is used. It gives proper response(Response code 200) when executed using Fiddler.

But when I run the same service on Jmeter using Http Request. It returns response code as 500 and gives

> "Request format is invalid: text/xml."

This in response data. I have tried changing it to many formats like "application/xml" etc but of no use.

[image]

[HTTP_Request][2][soap-rpc][3]

[soap_error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgiOM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I understood what was causing the problem and have rectified it. In the Path field of HTTP request, i had put the name of the web method(which was not needed so i removed it) i.e. suppose my url is *172.1.1.1:8082/abc.asmx/method* so in the path , i mentioned only "/abc.asmx" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set a Header Manager under your request that contains :

> Content-Type : application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8

Comment: Yes, I have done that. Still it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

1. Inspect what requests are being sent using `Request` tab of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener for both SOAP/XML-RPC and HTTP Request samplers. Detect any differences and apply the proper configuration so requests would be identical.
2. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and make sure it's configured to send the following headers:

   - `Content-Type` - `text/xml`
   - `SOAPAction` - required [SOAPAction](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html) header value. The value may be blank.

References:

- [Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html)
- [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)

Comment: Hi, I did the point no. 1 mentioned by you. I could not find a solution. Could you please help? I have attached two images in the question named as HTTP_Request and soap-rpc

Comment: You didn't do point #2 as I can see `application/soap+xml;` **instead of** `text/xml` and **don't see** the `SOAPAction` header

Comment: Also **uncheck** "Use multipart/form-data for POST"

Comment: Hard luck, I still get the same error. Screenshot attached "soap_error2" .

Comment: Mind the capital `C` in `Content-Type`.

Comment: What else could be the issue?

Comment: Well, I understood the problem and have rectified it. Now it gives proper response. Thank you for your help.

Comment: out of interest, what was the problem? if none of the answers matches can you please provide your own so people having a similar problem could see a solution?

Comment: Well, in the Path of HTTP request, i had put the name of the web method as well(which was not needed). I removed it and then run it, and it passed :)